# AWS Multicontainer Docker Environments - don't start

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i use the beanstalk-maven-pluginand like to deploy a Multicontainer to aws but i'm not able to do this. The Stack just failed with "Failed to launch environment." - that's it.

If i create the Environment with the same zip file via the beanstalk aws page, it works.

i created two service roles / iam

1) aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role - with the Policy: AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker, AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role

2) aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role with the same Policies like aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role

My files are:

Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "nginx-proxy",
      "image": "nginx:1.10",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 8080
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

.ebextensions/blockdevice-sdh.config

```
option_settings:
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    BlockDeviceMappings: /dev/xvdcz=:12:true:gp2,/dev/sdh=:24
```

.ebextensions/serviceroles.config

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
    option_name: IamInstanceProfile
    value: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role

  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
    option_name: ServiceRole
    value: aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role
```

and some data from the pom.xml

```
  <properties>
    <beanstalk.solutionStack>64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.3 running Multi-container Docker 1.11.1 (Generic)</beanstalk.solutionStack>
    <beanstalker.region>eu-central-1</beanstalker.region>
  </properties>
```

the console log from the instance don't show so much. i compared the cloud formation templates (one time from the mvn deploy and one time from the ElasticBeanstalk deploy via the webpage) and i don't see any important differences.

After checking all events, the only thing, wich one are different is that the mvn deployment not doing the ECS task

```
ECS task: arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:980585748732:task/b1098b24-d5ac-44e8-9987-e90e98fa0983 is RUNNING.
Starting new ECS task with awseb-Release-nebh2zbkfa:1.
Added instance [i-dd79c060] to your environment.
```

The documentation from Elasticbeanstalk sayed, that EB take care of creating and running this automatically. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html

but my zip file looks like this:

```
    0  07-15-16 21:33   .ebextensions/
  118  07-15-16 21:33   .ebextensions/blockdevice-sdh.config
   98  07-15-16 21:33   .ebextensions/customoptions.config
  268  07-15-16 21:33   .ebextensions/serviceroles.config
  292  07-15-16 00:02   Dockerrun.aws.json
```

i hope you've some idea, why the container not starts.

Thanks a lot 
Marcel